# How to create a child component using laravel 8 livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm creating a project using Laravel 8 and Livewire. I have created an admin panel using Livewire which I list in there the clients and their products. Now I want to create a child component connected with the admin component by clicking a button(ex. See Info btn). So that means I have to pass a ID of the client bc every client has different ID. And by clicking the client I want to open a new page
which shows the information of the client.

Could you suggest me a tutorial or a way how to do this?

Comment: We'll happily help you with your existing code, but this isn't a place to share tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can pass data into a component by passing additional parameters into the <livewire: tag.**

**Step 1: Passing Parameters**

For example, let's say we have a **child-client** component. Here's how you would pass in a **$client_id**.

```
<livewire:child-client :client_id="$client_id">
```

Alternatively, this is how you can pass in parameters using the Blade directive.

```
@livewire('child-client', ['client_id' => $client_id])
```

**Step 2: Receiving Parameters**

```
class ShowPost extends Component
{
    public $client_id;
   
    public function mount($client_id)
    {
        $this->client_id= $client_id;
    }
```

If any doubt, please don't hesitate to ask